# dualboot win11 + linux = BlInitalizeLibrary Failed 0xc00000bb

Tags: linux, windows, mac-osx, grub

Recently I wipe macbook pro disk (intel cpu) and installed win11. windows works without problems. The problem born when I installed on same disk linux debian with grub. Debian works but when I select win11 from grub menu I see this error:

```
BlInitalizeLibrary Failed 0xc00000bb
```

I found this link:

```
https://superuser.com/questions/1340248/triple-boot-mac-wont-boot-windows
```

[image]
[image]
I'd like avoid install again osx.

Installed also refind but same error problem.